# 'lookup' in FormulaR1C1 returns error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to run this line of code, I receive VBA error 1004.

```
Range("K38").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2, 1/(COUNTIF($K$36:$K37, WIP_Table[Resource Name])=0), WIP_Table[Resource Name]), """")"
```

The formula for the cell works when input into Excel manually.

Comment: You are using `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Formula`. **Sidenote:** You are using `.Select` to get an `ActiveCell` but there is no need to do so. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194) older post on SO.

Comment: You've also passed three arguments to COUNTIF, which won't work.

Comment: @Rory, no there is only two arguments, try it out in excel it works! It is just failing in vba though

Comment: @user11015000 Only because you just edited it!

Comment: That's how it was written in my code, I copied it across wrong. Not the source of the error anyway

Comment: Think that fixed it @JvdV thanks!

Comment: @user11015000 it should be “there are only two arguments”...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my comment to close this thread:

> You are using `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Formula`. **Sidenote:** You are using `.Select` to get an `ActiveCell` but there is no need to do so. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/9758194) older post on SO.